# Passport-http bad request

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I wanna make simple authentication with passport-http (DigestStrategy).
It is look like:

```
var DigestStrategy = require('passport-http').DigestStrategy;

passport.use('login', new DigestStrategy({ qop: 'auth' },
    function(login, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ login: login }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
            user.matchPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (!isMatch)
                {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                return done(null, user);
            })
        });
    }
));
```

and in POST /login

```
router.post('/',
    passport.authenticate('login', {session: false}),
    function(req, res) {
        if (req.user)
        {
            var expires = moment().add('hours', 1).valueOf();

            res.json({
                expires: expires,
                user: req.user.toJSON()
            });
        } 
        else
        {   
            console.log("send 401 ...");
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
});
```

I insert credentials in http form

```
div.loginbox
    form(name='login', action='/login', method='post')
        label(value='login')
        input(type='text', name='login')

        label(value='password')
        input(type='password', name='password')

        input(type='submit', value='Login')
```

But after that, i just get 400 Bad Request.

Comment: where's the code that you submit the facebook token to your server?

Comment: Typo in the following:
var expires = moment().add('houres', 1).valueOf()

'houres' should be hours

Comment: @NicholasNg There is no facebook auth, i just wanna simple auth with login and password that stored in db.

Comment: @row248 ops my bad.... did you try logging where it stopped? also check this [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/blob/master/examples/digest/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are mixing some HTTP authentication with custom authentication by posting form data as credentials.

By posting credentials using HTML form there is no implicit HTTP Digest authentication. You need to send some special headers for initiating any HTTP authentication. There you can choose *Basic* or *Digest* authentication. This is causing browser to prompt user for name and password resulting in special HTTP header that is then managed by chosen DigestStrategy. **Bad Request** was issued for HTTP header is actually missing the required header information for performing authentication.

If you want to log in using form you either might want to use LocalStrategy of passport-local instead or probably use AJAX for managing client-side Digest authentication yourself though I'd stick with the former.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use [http-auth](http://http-auth.info) that also has passport integration:

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var digest = auth.digest ({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htdigest" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Application setup.
var app = express();

// Setup strategy.
var passport = require('passport');
passport.use(auth.passport(digest));

// Setup route.
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('http', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
});
```